# Parallelization of heterogeous job processors

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates

Suppose we have some functions like:

```
R1* process_input1(I1*);
R2* process_input2(I1*);
R1* process_input3(I2*);
//... etc
```

These functions are cpu-intensive operations that take a variable amount of time. However, these can all run independently from each other and therefore good candidates for running in parallel. They are responsible for allocating memory for the R(esult) types.

We also have some other functions like:

```
void process_result1(R1*);
void process_result2(R1*);
void process_result3(R2*);
//... etc
```

These consume the R(esult)s and are responsible for deallocating the memory they occupy.

The main loop is written as follows:

```
void event_loop(Queue& some_queue)
{
   while (job = some_queue.get_front())
   {
      switch(job.getCmdCode())
      {
      case CMD1:
         R1* pResult = process_input1(job.getI1());
         process_result1(pResult);
         break;

      case CMD2:
         R2* pResult = process_input2(job.getI1());
         process_result3(pResult);
         break;

      case CMD3:
         R1* pResult = process_input3(job.getI2());
         process_result2(pResult);
         break;

      //... etc
      }
   }
}
```

As you can see, the `process_input` methods are serialized. The goal is to parallelize the `process_input` methods to improve throughput, while still maintaining the order in which `process_result` methods are called.

So we design a class with an interface like this:

```
class ParallelSequencer
{
public:
   ParallelSequencer(size_t nThreads);

   template <typename I, typename R>
   enqueue(I* input, R* (*process_input)(I*), void (*process_result)(R*));
};
```

The main loop now becomes:

```
void event_loop(Queue& some_queue)
{
   ParallelSequencer sequencer(NUM_SEQUENCER_THREADS);

   while (job = some_queue.get_front())
   {
      switch(job.getCmdCode())
      {
      case CMD1:
         sequencer.enqueue(job.getI1(), process_input1, process_result1);
         break;

      case CMD2:
         sequencer.enqueue(job.getI1(), process_input2, process_result3);
         break;

      case CMD3:
         sequencer.enqueue(job.getI2(), process_input3, process_result2);
         break;

      //... etc
      }
   }
}
```

To implement this, we would need to queue up two types of tuples:

```
template <typename I, typename R>
struct Input 
{
   I* data;
   R* (*process)(I*);
}
```

Queued up as enqueue() gets called and removed as a thread picks up the job.

```
template <typename R>
struct Output
{
   R* data;
   void (*process)(R*);
}
```

Queued up when a thread is done calling `process_input()`, and removed before/after calling `process_result()`.

How do you declare, in a typesafe manner, a queue that contains a sequence of these two data structures?

Is this a completely wrong approach to fix this problem?

I understand this can be done using `void*` everywhere, but where's the fun in that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you right, but if I'm correct what you want to do can be done with a simple Interface:

```
struct IInput {
    // I actually didnt understand where and how you want to process the outputs...
    // It seemed to me that the output is processed sequentially so I'm pushing it to a SerialSequencer
    void process_input(SerialSequencer& sequence) = 0;
}

struct IOutput {
    void process_output() = 0;
}

template<typename R>
struct Output : public IOutput {
    R* data;
    void (*process)(R*);

    void process_output() override {
       process(data);
    }
}

template<typename I, typename R>
struct Input : public IInput {
    I* data;
    R* (*process_I)(I*);
    void (*process_O)(R*);

    void process_input(SerialSequencer& output_sequencer) override {
        R* result = process_i(data);
        Output<R> output = {result, process_O};
        output_sequencer.enqueue(output); 
    }
}
```

The `ParallelSequencer` just has to accept a pointer to the Interface struct:

```
class ParallelSequencer
{
public:
   ParallelSequencer(size_t nThreads);

   void enqueue(std::shared_ptr<IInput> input_ptr);
};
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
void event_loop(Queue& some_queue)
{
   ParallelSequencer sequencer(NUM_SEQUENCER_THREADS);

   while (job = some_queue.get_front())
   {
      switch(job.getCmdCode())
      {
      case CMD1:
         std::shared_ptr<Input<I1, R1> input_ptr = 
         std::make_shared<Input<I1, R1>>(ob.getI1(), process_input1, process_result1));
         sequencer.enqueue(input_ptr);
         break;
      //... etc
      }
   }
}
```

And the calling thread pops a IInput and calls the pure virtual function:

```
void thread_func() {
    while(something) {
        std::shared_ptr<IInput> input_ptr = sequencer.pop();
        input_ptr->process_input(serial_sequencer);
    }
}
```